# How to resolve dependencies of AppImage

Tags: 18.04, appimage, uml

I'm using StarUML to design UML diagram
StarUML X64 3.1.0 (2019/03/06) runs perfectly on my ubuntu 18 LTS X64 bit.
But the 4 newest versions, are very laggy(moving any object is very slow)
Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to deal with it

1. Uninstalled the previous version
2. Installed X86 bit
3. Run it with `--appimage-extract`
4. Installed appimage daemon to fully integrate my appimage in the system (icons, launcher, desktop entry)

That's it, Not much but it works